# Unable to redirect after writing to database (OpenCart)

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, opencart, opencart-module

I'm developing a custom OpenCart (version: 2.3.0.2) payment module.

At the back-end side (admin folder), I got everything running perfectly as expected.

Unlike the back-end (catalog folder), the behavioural flow works as expected except when I log transaction details to the database using the **`$this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory()`** helper function; I can write successfully details to the database, but my redirect after login the transaction fails.

As such, my redirect work effectively when I comment out the helper function (which I use to write payment details to the database) above.

I handle my redirect with jQuery, passing the URL for the given location from my catalog controller payment extension.

Below is the content of my catalog controller payment extension file located at **`opencart/catalog/controller/extension/payment/my-pay-module.php`**:

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionPaymentMyPayModule extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('extension/payment/my-pay-module');

        $data['text_payment_details'] = $this->language->get('text_payment_details');
        $data['text_loading'] = $this->language->get('text_loading');

        $data['entry_issuer_hint'] = $this->language->get('entry_issuer_hint');
        $data['entry_instrument'] = $this->language->get('entry_instrument');

        $data['button_confirm'] = $this->language->get('button_confirm');
        $data['button_back'] = $this->language->get('button_back');

        return $this->load->view('extension/payment/my-pay-module', $data);
    }

    public function send() {
        $this->load->model('checkout/order');

        $order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);

        $request  = 'merchant_id=' . urlencode($this->config->get('my_pay_module_merchant_id'));
        $request .= '&order_id=' . urlencode($this->session->data['order_id']);
        $request .= '&total_amount=' . urlencode($this->currency->format($order_info['total'], $order_info['currency_code'], 1.00000, false));
        $request .= '&instrument=' . urlencode($this->request->post['instrument']);
        $request .= '&issuer_hint=' . urlencode($this->request->post['issuer_hint']);
        $request .= '&user_phone_no=' . urlencode($order_info['telephone']);
        $request .= '&user_email=' . urlencode($order_info['email']);

        $curl = curl_init('https://example.com/v1/api');

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);// JSON response: {"status":"200","success":"true","message":"Payment received successfully."}

        curl_close($curl);

        // Create response object
        $custPayResponse = array(
            'data'       => json_decode($response)
        );

        // Define redirect URL for success
        $success = array(
            'redirect'   => $this->url->link('checkout/success', '', true)
        );

        // Define redirect URL for failure
        $failed = array(
            'redirect'   => $this->url->link('checkout/failed', '', true)
        );

        // Check success and write to OpenCart
        if ($custPayResponse['data']->success == true) {

            // Set transaction details
            $reference = '';

            $reference .= 'Issuer Hint: ';

            if (isset($response)) {
                $reference .= $this->request->post['issuer_hint'] . "\n";
            }

            $reference .= 'Instrument: ';

            if (isset($response)) {
                $reference .= $this->request->post['instrument'] . "\n";
            }

            // Write to database
            $this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory($this->session->data['order_id'], $this->config->get('my_pay_module_order_status_id'), $reference, true);

            // Merge response object and redirect URL (success)
            $GLOBALS['params'] = array_merge($custPayResponse, $success);
        } else {
            // Merge response object and redirect URL (failure)
            $GLOBALS['params'] = array_merge($custPayResponse, $failed);
        }

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($GLOBALS['params']));
    }
}
```

and the content of my catalog view file which is located at: **`opencart/catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/payment/my-pay-module.tpl`**:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset id="payment">
    <legend><?php echo $text_payment_details; ?></legend>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-issuer-hint"><?php echo $entry_issuer_hint; ?></label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="issuer_hint">Option1</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="issuer_hint">Option2</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="issuer_hint">Option3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-pymt-instrument"><?php echo $entry_instrument; ?></label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="instrument" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_instrument; ?>" id="input-instrument" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_confirm; ?>" id="button-confirm" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button-confirm').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=extension/payment/my-pay-module/send',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#payment :input'),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

            if (json['redirect']) {
                // Sample expected result: http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=checkout/success
                // Using a full location for that reason; not location.href as result is not as desired.
                location = json['redirect'];
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I get no error in both browser's console and OpenCart error log.

What am I doing wrong and can I possibly fix it?

Comment: shouldn't it be `location.href = ...`?

Comment: @Jeff: Did tried as you suggested; it's the same result as narrated above.

Comment: what is the `JSON.stringify` for? You don't need that! - and that's probably the problem -> json['redirect'] will be false

Comment: Hello @Jeff: I've just updated my post based on your suggestions so as to show the current state of the code; the result is however still the same. Edited portion of the view file is: **`success: function(json) {}`**.

Answer (score 0):

supposing the received json looks something like that:

```
json = {"redirect": "page2.html", "param2": "foo"};

//....
success: function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    // JSON.stringify(json); // you wanna keep the json, json['redirect'] will return a string anyway

    if (json['redirect']) {
        // you need to set location.href here, not the whole location object!
        location.href = json['redirect'];
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: The received JSON looks as in your snippet above. Edited as you've suggested; it still doesn't work. The problem persists as no data get passed to the view when I write to the database with **`$this->model_checkout_order->addOrderHistory($this->session->data['order_id'], $this->config->get('my_pay_module_order_status_id'), $reference, true);`**. When I comment out that very script in my controller, the data get passed to the view and my redirect works as expected but the only problem here is that I get no transaction details saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bug in the `addOrderHistory()` method - probably caused by an ocmod or vqmod, or possibly your mail settings.  Any fatal error in there can cause the payment controller to hang and give no ajax response.  I can almost guarantee you'll find errors in your webserver's error log relating to the source of the problem if any reasonable logging level is enabled.

Comment: I was actually able to resolve it, but yet to post the solution and approach; you are right on the *mail settings*, but I got it tracing, back the fatal error from AJAX (having added **`error: function()`**). No bug in `addOrderHistory()`. Great insight though.

Comment: the `addOrderHistory()` method sends an email so in all likelihood the issue in your mail settings causes it to hang.  I've seen this kind of thing a bunch of times and mail is the usual suspect